# Making a button to end of modal based on device size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap3 where I am using modals to render a form..Is there any way to make modal to take entire height of mobile based on device window size.Also, I have a button inside the modal.The button should always be at end of the modal.I am trying using jquery..Is there any way with pure CSS

```
<div class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div></div>
```

I need this bootstrap modal to take entire height of mobile page and modal-footer container should always be at end of cloud irrespective of modal-body content

Comment: Could you post some of your relevant code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write your own CSS so you set the min height of the modal to 100%... Because the modal backdrop is 100% height, so `min-height: 100%` should work.

Comment: This worked and modal took entire height of the mobile..What can I do for making modal-footer container to be at end of the modal ?

Comment: You could just ajust the height % from your `modal-header`, `modal-body`, `modal-footer`, i.e. 15%, 70%, 15%